# Efficient (spatial) Network Neighbors?

Tags: python, geospatial, arcgis

I would like to identify the Kth order neighbors of an edge on a network, specifically the neighbors of a large set of streets.  For example, I have a street that I'm interested in looking at, call this the focal street.  For each focal street I want to find the streets that share an intersection, these are the first order neighbors.  Then for each of those streets that share an intersection with the focal street I would like to find their neighbors (these would be the second order neighbors), and so on...

Calculating the first order neighbors using ArcGIS' geoprocessing library (arcpy) took 6+ hours, second order neighbors are taking 18+ hours.  Needless to say I want to find a more efficient solution.  I have created a python dictionary which is keyed on each street and contains the connected streets as values.  For example:

```
st2neighs = {street1: [street2, street3, street5], street2: [street1, street4], ...}.
```

street 1 is connected to street 2, 3, 5; street 2 is connected to street 1 and 4; etc..  There are around 30,000 streets in the study area most have fewer than 7 connected streets.  **A pickled version of the data used in the code below [IS HERE](http://www.filedropper.com/streetdata)**.

I assumed that knowing the first order neighbors would allow me to efficiently trace the higher order neighbors.  But the following code is providing incorrect results:

```
##Select K-order neighbors from a set of sampled streets.
##saves in dictionary format such that
##the key is the sampled street and the neighboring streets are the values

##################
##IMPORT LIBRARIES
##################

import random as random
import pickle

#######################
##LOAD PICKLED DATA
#######################

seg_file = open("seg2st.pkl", "rb")
st_file = open("st2neighs.pkl", "rb")
seg2st = pickle.load(seg_file)
st2neigh = pickle.load(st_file)

##################
##DEF FUNCTIONS
##################

##Takes in a dict of segments (key) and their streets (values).
##returns the desired number of sampled streets per segment
##returns a dict keyed segment containing tlids.
def selectSample(seg2st, nbirths):
    randSt = {}
    for segK in seg2st.iterkeys():
        ranSamp = [int(random.choice(seg2st[segK])) for i in xrange(nbirths)]
        randSt[segK] = []
        for aSamp in ranSamp:
                randSt[segK].append(aSamp)

    return randSt

##Takes in a list of all streets (keys) and their first order neighbors (values)
##Takes in a list of sampled  streets
##returns a dict of all sampled streets and their neighbors.
##Higher order selections should be possible with findMoreNeighbors
##logic is the same but replacing sample (input) with output from
##findFirstNeighbors

def findFirstNeighbors(st2neigh, sample):
    compSts = {}
    for samp in sample.iterkeys():
        for rSt in sample[samp]:
            if rSt not in compSts:
                compSts[rSt] = []
            for compSt in st2neigh[rSt]:
                compSts[rSt].append(compSt)

    return compSts

def findMoreNeighbors(st2neigh, compSts):
    for aSt in compSts:
        for st in compSts[aSt]:
            for nSt in st2neigh[st]:
                if nSt not in compSts[aSt]:
                    compSts[aSt].append(nSt)
    moreNeighs = compSts
    return moreNeighs

#####################
##The nHoods
#####################

samp = selectSample(seg2st, 1)
n1 = findFirstNeighbors(st2neigh, samp)
n2 = findMoreNeighbors(st2neigh, n1)
n3 = findMoreNeighbors(st2neigh, n2)

#####################
##CHECK RESULTS
#####################
def checkResults(neighList):
    cntr = {}
    for c in neighList.iterkeys():
        cntr[c] = 0
        for a in neighList[c]:
            cntr[c] += 1
    return cntr

##There is an error no streets **should** have 2000+ order neighbors
c1 = checkResults(n1)
c2 = checkResults(n2)
c3 = checkResults(n3)
```

Help!

Comment: You might consider asking here also: http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like what you want to implement is the following: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations

It is actually a straight-forward algorithm. Let R be the relation "is a first order neighbor", therefore if two streets x,y are in R then x is a first order neighbor of y. So, for second order neighbor you want to compute R composed with R. For third order neighbors (R composed R) composed R. And so on.

Comment: Yes, composition of relations is a nice formalization of the intended behavior of the code.  However, I'm still not clear on why the code doesn't work as expected...

Comment: I was not able to download your zip file, tried 3 times did not work (imcomplete headers). But it seems like your FindFirstNeighbors is broken. It seems like FindMoreNeighbors indeed implements the composition.